# For every 4th and 5th element, apply this class to HTML

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The 1st and 2nd rows fetched will have 'case-study--large' class (50% width). 2nd, 3rd and 4th will have 'case-study' class (33% width) and then back to two large and so on...

To apply this, I'm running a for loop using the following logic:

```
    <?php
       $casesize = "case-card";
       for ($counter = 1; $counter < 100; $counter++ ) {
           if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
                $casesize = "case-card--large";
         }  
       }
    ?>
```

However, all my div's are using the 'case-card--large' styling (50% width)? And if I tune my code to the following:

```
    <?php
       for ($counter = 1; $counter < 100; $counter++ ) {
           if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
               $casesize = "case-card--large";
         } else {
               $casesize = "case-card"; 
           }
       }
    ?>
```

All div's now have 'case-card' styling? Unsure why this is happening?

I want it to look like the following:

```
   | Large | Large |
|Small | Small | Small |
   | Large | Large |
         ...
```

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: initial;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.case-card--large {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.case-card {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 393px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="<?php echo $casesize;?>" ?>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your div inside the loop?

Comment: So where do you output the HTML. It does not look like you do it in the loop??

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the value in the loop, so you have to put it back if you want to test again :

```
<?php
    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 100; $counter++ ) {
        $casesize = "case-card";
        if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
            $casesize = "case-card--large";
        }
        // Do something with casesize
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using $casesize var outside the loop. Try it inside the loop

Replace this:

```
<div class="<?php echo $casesize;?>" ?>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this:

```
    <?php
    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 100; $counter++ ) {
        echo '<div class="';
        if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
            echo 'case-card--large';
        } else {
            echo 'case-card';
        }
        echo '"><div class="wrapper"><p>Dummy Text</p></div></div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use pure CSS?

```
.class:nth-child(4), .class:nth-child(5) {
    /** your css code **/
}
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

You could to this in **full CSS** using [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class:

```
// Large
.yourclass {
    // Default styling
}

// Small
.yourclass:nth-child(5n+3), .yourclass:nth-child(5n+4), .yourclass:nth-child(5n+5) {
    // Specific styling for "small" elements
}
```

A useful resource to test your `nth-child` selectors: [nth tester](https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/).
There are many `nth-` selectors, see [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Comment: Cheers, for your answer! yeah it makes much more sense to do it via CSS. I've applied your suggestion, but can seem to get two large images, can you see why? https://jsfiddle.net/ma8gd9or/4/

Comment: Hi @Freddy, in your Fiddle, the text color is white (you don't see anything), and you could set borders (to `.case-card--large`) to understand how your blocks are placed. Is it better now ?